# assign value to label inside ResourceDictionary in code behind using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms.

I am using the following codes in xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:Syncfusion ="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfCalendar.XForms"
             x:Class="MyProject.View.WOList">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="weathertemplate">

                <Grid  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="txtopen" Text="{Binding Date.Day}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  FontSize="16"  />
....
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
...
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I want to assign "Text" to label(x:Name="txtopen") on code behind. But code behind the "txtopen" is not shown.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You have a binding there so why not to set a default value on the ViewModel level?

Comment: I want to assign the other value again on the button click action.

Comment: DataBinding is in place .. once again why not to use it?

Comment: i want to change different background color for the particular label on button click.

Comment: Use IValueConverter => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: Can you please share your .cs file code?